# How to map a table to itself in Doctrine ORM using a self referencing relationship.

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

There is a `User` class which has two types of users such as `patient` and `doctor`. So, I created another attribute that is used to describe the relation between `patient` and `doctor`, a doctor can have many patients. So, If the user is patent, he should have `doctorId`, if not, the `doctorId` is NULL.

Here is my `User.orm.yml`:

```
Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: User
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 30
        lastName:
            type: string
            length: 30
        email:
            type: string
            length: 60
            unique: true
        username:
            type: string
            length: 10
            unique: true
        password:
            type: string
            length: 100
            unique: false
        doctorId:
            type: integer
            unique: false
            nullable: true
        dateCreated:
            type: datetime
    manyToMany:
        roles:
            targetEntity: Role
            mappedBy: users
```

How can I map the `doctorId` as a foreign key that refers to the `id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find instructions for **self-referencing One-To-Many relations** in the Doctrine documentation:

```
User:
  type: entity
  oneToMany:
    patients
      targetEntity: User
      mappedBy:     doctor
  manyToOne:
    doctor:
      targetEntity: User
      inversedBy:   patients
```

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing

Comment: My answer provides a working example-mapping for a self-referencing OneToMany relationship. The link may be outdated and I'll update it now to work again. Next time feel free to **edit** the answer yourself if you have suggestions for improvements or found a non-working link. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With doctrine you might want to take a look at association mapping. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html. In your case you are after a one to many self referencing relationship http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing.

A doctor can have many patients but can a patient have many doctors? If so you have a many to many relationship which you could map out using a cross Reference table as the joining table. The best way to model this I feel is to have a userTypeId in your users Table where a value of 1 could be doctor, 2 a patient etc. Then a doctor can have many patients but also a patient can see many doctors. This would also be extensible if you added new user types like nurses etc.